# Port android / android tv on nokia booklet 3G

Tags: android, nokia, television

is it possible to port android (android tv) on Nokia booklet 3G , i like the booklet hardware (built in 3g modem and hdmi port and overall build) but windows 7 is horrible.

it would be great to have android with android tv port on nokia booklet 3G

any idea how to do?

Answer (score 0):

its possible.

"porting android" for the most part means getting the linux kernel and drivers running on the hardware.

In this case that system is based on an atom cpu /intel graphics so getting it to boot would probably be really easy.

Getting everything working may be hard or easy depending on what components in the thing already have linux drivers and which need to be either adapted from other existing drivers or written fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Its sure possible in most easy way, but experience afterwards is not that rewarding as of now. I tried and its a let down as the Android doesn't seem to be running for Netbooks as of now. Most of the basic things keep on crashing though I liked the looks.

Check out the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=273L24MLydw

Will post on my blog soon